# How to style data-scribe in CSS

Tags: html, css

How do I style a span by its data-scribe.

eg. in my html there is:

```
<span data-scribe="element:verified_badge">✔</span>
```

How could I add CSS styling to this specific span?

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and do something as simple as:

```
span[data-scribe] {
    color:green;
}
```

or more specific like:

```
span[data-scribe="element:verified_badge"] {
    color:green;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rg5atxbt/)**